# Regex expression not working in PHP

Tags: php, regex

The code below is what I am using to parse a return from another function

```
$LinkRegex = '/(?!(\d+\/\d+)\s*(\d{7,10})\s*)(?<Link>[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}:?[0-9]?[0-9]?)/';

preg_match_all($LinkRegex, $row, $LinkMatches);

foreach($LinkMatches["Link"] as $Links)
        {
            mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Links (Order, Links) VALUES ('". $Order ."','". $Links ."')");
        }
```

This is an example of a string I am matching

```
21/8 664922003 0 0 1 21/1:26,21/1:27,21/1:28
```

Right now $LinkMatches["Link"] is returning only a single value '21/1:2'

It should be returning the following 3 values

```
21/1:26
21/1:27
21/1:28
```

Which the regex above does when I use the http://regex101.com tester. is there something about PHP that is interfering with the returns on this expression? I am using the preg_match_all since I needed the /g flag which I believe should be correct. This code works fine on other likes that do not contain the optional ":xx".

Comment: `order` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html either wrap it in backticks, or give it another name. Seems obvious that error reporting isn't on.

Comment: did you bother trying to do `var_dump($LinkMatches)` to see what you got back from the regex?

Comment: https://eval.in/164403

Comment: @ Fred - $Order is not the actual variable I am using, I cut it down for simplicity sake and to remove company sensitive information.
@Marc - that is how I know it is giving back only a single non-correct variable

Comment: I call 'em as I see 'em ;-) *Plus,* I wasn't referring to `$Order` (variable), but to `(Order, Links)` in `INSERT INTO Links (Order, Links)`

Comment: well you are saying "Match a bunch of stuff but don't capture it, followed by your `digit/digit:digit` stuff. So you're getting exactly what you requested. the first `digit/digit:digit` after the stuff that shouldn't be captured. the 2nd and 3rd bits won't get matched, since they're not preceded by the "don't capture" bits.

Comment: found extraneous code one of our contractors had put int there that I was not aware of before that was causing issues. Issue solved closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right now $LinkMatches["Link"] is returning only a single value
>   '21/1:2'

This seems to work fine when using `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all("/(?!(\d+\/\d+)\s*(\d{7,10})\s*)(?<Link>[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}:?[0-9]?[0-9]?)/", "21/8 664922003 0 0 1 21/1:26,21/1:27,21/1:28", $matches, null, 0);


// Dump the output for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21/1:26
            [1] => 21/1:27
            [2] => 21/1:28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

    [Link] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21/1:26
            [1] => 21/1:27
            [2] => 21/1:28
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21/1:26
            [1] => 21/1:27
            [2] => 21/1:28
        )

)
```

That said, you can make this a bit more readable if you use a non-capturing group setting like this `?:`:

```
preg_match_all("/(?!(?:\d+\/\d+)\s*(?:\d{7,10})\s*)(?<Link>[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}:?[0-9]?[0-9]?)/", "21/8 664922003 0 0 1 21/1:26,21/1:27,21/1:28", $matches);

// Dump the output for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would then be this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21/1:26
            [1] => 21/1:27
            [2] => 21/1:28
        )

    [Link] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21/1:26
            [1] => 21/1:27
            [2] => 21/1:28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21/1:26
            [1] => 21/1:27
            [2] => 21/1:28
        )

)
```